# Cordova, Requirements check failed for JDK 8 ('1.8.*')! Detected version: 11.0.2 on Mac OS

Tags: macos, java, jdk, macos-mojave, apache-cordova

I'm trying to run simple project with cordova on **MacOS Mojave 10.14.4**:
[screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ABuj7.png)

I tried to change the environment variable `JAVA_HOME` in several ways:

```
export JAVA_HOME="`/usr/libexec/java_home -v '1.8*'`"
```

does not help

```
export JAVA_HOME="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_191.jdk/Contents/Home"
```

does not help
I created files `~/bash_profile` and `~/profile` and put this line into each of them:

```
export JAVA_HOME="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_191.jdk/Contents/Home"
```

Then, I ran

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

and also tried

```
soruce ~/.profile
```

And still I had the problem with JDK version.

Answer (score 0):

I gave up trying to set up Android JDK manually, I downloaded Android Studio and let it set everything up. After Android Studio was installed I found that ANDROID_HOME is not defined, so I opened `~/.bash_profile` file and changed it:

```
export JAVA_HOME="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home"
export ANDROID_HOME="$HOME/Library/Android/sdk"
export PATH="${PATH}:/$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:/$ANDROID_HOME/tools:/$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin"
```

Because of problems with configuring JDK I also gave up using **cordova** and switched to **NativeScript** which does not requiere JDK version 8. **NativeScript** miraculously picked up new system variables form **bash_profile** file. I still don't why without Android Studio I couldn't change the system environment variables.